# Trying to print the lines after writing them to an ouput file (java)

Tags: java

I have a problem. I'm  basically asked to use a method to print from an output file. So to start off I actually began filling the output file with lines..then when I tried to actually read them and print them on the screen there was a slight problem. I actually used the 'debug' option and the problem turned out to be within the ' line = input.nextLine()' line of code but i don't really know why..I mean that's how we get to read from an output file...help would be appreciated.

Here's my work so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Problem_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintWriter outFile = null;
        File f1 = new File("try.txt");


        try {

            outFile = new PrintWriter("try.txt");
            outFile.println("First line!");
            outFile.println("Second line!");
            outFile.println("Third line!");

            cat(f1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            outFile.print("(1) Exception: " + e.getMessage()); // no such element exception
        }

        outFile.close();
    }
    /*
     * outFile = new PrintWriter(f1); outFile.println("Line 1");
     * outFile.println("Line 2"); outFile.println("Line 3"); outFile.print("");
     * cat(f1); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("(1)Exception: " +
     * e.getMessage()); } outFile.close(); }
     */

    public static void cat(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = null;
        String line = "";

        input = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        //line = input.next();
        //  line = input.nextLine();// this line calls the exception in the main method

        while ((line != null)) {
            System.out.println("In the while loop");
            System.out.println("Line  323" + line);
            return;
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to close the file *before* trying to read from it. Reason being that the buffer might not be flushed yet so there's actually nothing in the file yet when you try to read it.

Comment: "There was a slight problem" - what problem? You talk about "this line calls the exception" - what exception? An exception is *thrown* and *caught*, not called.

Comment: I did that, but it actually didn't work

Comment: "This line calls the exception" what i mean is when I debugged..there was an exception " NoSuchElement" exception..i basically wrote that comment to know where the problem was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code to be:

```
try {

    outFile = new PrintWriter("try.txt");
    outFile.println("First line!");
    outFile.println("Second line!");
    outFile.println("Third line!");

    outFile.close();


 } 
 catch (Exception e) {
    outFile.print("(1) Exception: " + e.getMessage()); // no such element exception
 }

 cat(f1);
```

You can't read what you written before you close the file.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked! I always thought closing the outFile should be done at  like the very end...thanks for the help!